# Batch goto not working properly?

Tags: batch-file, goto

I am working on a small project that asks for input and then does to one of two variables.  Whenever I make a choice it always goes to the first choice no matter what I choose. How could I correct this?

```
echo Do you need to get out fast? (Y or N)
set /p choice=
if %choice% == "Y" goto :Skip
if %choice% == "y" goto :Skip
if %choice% == "N" goto :Next
if %choice% == "n" goto :Next
cls
:Skip
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
start .\App\Quick.bat
goto :eof
EXIT
:Next
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
start .\App\Slow.bat
pause
goto :eof
EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

`choice` command is a simpler and more efficient way to get user input.

```
choice /c:yn /m "Do you need to get out fast? (Y or N)"
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto Skip
if %errorlevel% == 2 goto Next
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped!